# Converting object type column to float type converts all to Nan?

Tags: python, pandas, object

While converting my object type columns to Float type, all my values are turned to Nan.

I checked the dtype of columns post conversion which shows all are float type. Hence succesful in that regard.
**But Why does it produces Nan values**.

This is the code I'm using. Both versions of code below are producing same results.

```
data.M0=pd.to_numeric(data.M0, errors='coerce')
data['M1'] = data['M1'].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')
```

[image: Below is the pic of output dataframe.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` returns `NaN` with invalid parsing for entries that can't be converted to float values:

[Official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) states that:

> errors{‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
>
> If ‘raise’, then
> invalid parsing will raise an exception.
>
> **If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.**
>
> If ‘ignore’, then invalid parsing will return the input.

Probably, your elements in the dataframe are non-numeric and can't be converted.

Comment: At last just fixed it in the excel sheet. That was the root of the problem.

Comment: @yashagarwal  Great that you found the root cause and solved the problem!   Happy programming and have a nice day  :-)

Answer (score 0):

`pd.to_numeric` has an `errors` argument which can be `ignore`, `raise` and `coerce`.

`coerce` sets to `NaN` if the values aren't numeric-like values.

As mentioned in the [docs]9https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).

> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as `NaN`.